# Find element's siblings with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <span class="">TextA</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="">TextB</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I can find element span with TextA, and from there, I want to find span with textB, then click on it (which is not available to find it alone). So I used xpath like this:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'TextA')]/following-sibling::span")).click();
```

I got exception Element is not found. I assumed these spans are siblings ?!. Can anyone help me in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I got exception Element is not found. I assumed these spans are siblings ?

*These two spans are not siblings* - they are children of different elements and cannot be siblings.

Instead of `following-sibling`, you may use the [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) axis:

```
//span[contains(.,'TextA')]/following::span
```

Or, you may get the `div` element that contains the `span` with `TextA` text and then get it's following sibling:

```
//div[contains(span, 'TextA')]/following-sibling::div/span
```

Comment: @LouisT okay, then there is something else we are missing. Is this element inside an iframe?

Comment: It's not inside an iframe, just pure HTML, and a lot of div tags. I did a workaround without using xpath though, and it did the work. But of course, I would like to know why it doesn't work with xpath and following-sibling. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LouisT interesting, the expressions themselves look good to me. Could be that the actual HTML does not correspond to the one in the question. Is there ay way you can make your problem reproducible for us? Say, provide a link to the target web page or post the relevant part of the HTML? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>`'s aren't siblings.  if the `<span>`'s were siblings, they'd have to be adjacent.

for example:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <span class="">TextA</span>
      <span class="">TextB</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

In this case, they are siblings and your selector would work.

The elements that are actually siblings, are the `<div>`s.

The xpath that could work for you, would be:

```
//span[contains(.,'TextA')]/../following-sibling::div/span
```